# Periodicity of a constant signal!

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, periodic

This can be a very silly question, but I'm quite confused:

1. If we take the Fourier transform of any constant signal, we get an impulse at zero, which says that its frequency is zero and, hence, it is non-repeating and its period is infinity.
2. By the definition of a periodic signal, $$F(z+p) = F(z)$$ therefore, for a constant function $$F(z) = c$$ $$F(z+p) = c, \forall p >0$$ Therefore, a constant function is periodic, but its period is undefined or can be defined as anything.

Which of the above arguments are correct and why? Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the least positive $p$, which does not exist for a constant function. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function#cite_note-1

Comment: i would vote for the constant function being a periodic function that can have any period.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson by that reasoning, _all_ periodic signals can have any period $p' = n\cdot p$ (with integral $n$). That's ugly because it means the period is never really well-defined; hence as Atul Ingle says, the definition of **the** period is actually the _least positive_ $p$ that fulfills $F(z+p) \equiv F(z)$.

Comment: that is true, Leftie.  any periodic signal that is periodic with period $P$ is also periodic with period $2P$ or $3P$.

Comment: Reading more about this, I see that when someone says "period" it is usually ambiguous whether they mean *the* period or *a* period. Some prefer saying "least period" to remove this ambiguity. Again, some require least period to be strictly positive (like that wiki page in my previous comment), while others are ok with allowing zero period. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPeriod.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Period.html
In the end I guess it doesn't really matter, as long as you define precisely what you mean by period and stick to it.

Comment: There are different standards. A similar question was closed on SE.math [Is a constant function periodic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385273/257503)

Comment: @AtulIngle You're right, and I think one also needs to see which definitions are more useful in one's specific field. Allowing 0 to be a period may make sense to a mathematician, but if you want to classify signals as periodic or non-periodic, as we do in SP, then it makes more sense to restrict the period to be larger than zero. As many other things, it's a matter both of convention and convenience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you say, the constant function is periodic. A signal $x(t)$ is said to be periodic with period $p$ or to have a period $p$ if there exists a $p>0$ such that $x(t+p)=x(t)$ for all real numbers $t$. Note that I said "a period" instead of "the period" -- periodic signals have an infinite number of periods, maybe even an uncountable infinite of them!

Often, what is referred to as *the* period of a signal is actually more formally described as the "fundamental period", which is the smallest among all periods.

So, a constant signal is periodic, it has an uncountably infinite number of periods (since any real number $p>0$ is a period), but it does not have a fundamental period.

Comment: "periodic signals may have many (even an infinite) number of periods." Actually, all periodic functions have an infinite number of periods.

Comment: @leonbloy You're right, of course -- edited to remark on what might be actually surprising (the number of periods may be an uncountable infinite).

Comment: Edited to add a few words. Please roll back if you don't like the changes I made.  I like your answer much better than the accepted one.

Comment: "periodic signals may have many (even an infinite) number of periods." Actually, all periodic functions have an infinite number of periods > Well, this assertion depends a lot of where you locate $t$. With a torus shape one might have only a finite number of "different" periods (within a ring structure). Yes, it's a little bit pedantic :)

Comment: The number of possible periods of a constant is aleph one, as opposed to non-constant periodic waveforms which have aleph zero.  Two different infinities.

Comment: @hotpaw2 To be even more pedantic, that's only correct if you assume the continuum hypothesis. Otherwise, the number of periods of a constant function is 2^(aleph zero), which may not be equal to aleph one.

Answer (score 4):

When you are in doubt, use the **limiting approach** as an aid in your deductions:

For example, you can consider a constant signal $x_C(t)=1$ as the limit of a periodic sine wave $x_p(t)= \cos(\omega_0 t)$ when the frequency goes to zero; i.e:

$$x_C(t) = 1 = \lim_{\omega_0 \to 0} \cos(\omega_0 t) $$

And you now that the Fourier transform of a sine wave is a frequency impulse located at $\omega = \omega_0$ ; i.e., $$\mathcal{F}\{\cos(\omega_0 t) \} = \pi \delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \pi \delta(\omega + \omega_0) $$

And therefore in the limiting case the signal $x_C(t)$ will have the Fourier transform of $$\mathcal{F}\{1\} = 2\pi \delta(\omega - 0) = 2\pi \delta(\omega) $$

Indeed the two impulse from right and left converge it the middle and add up !

At this point then, you don't have to consider whether the definition of periodicity applies or makes sense for the signal $x_C(t)=1$, since it's a degenerate case. Yet if you wish you can consider that its period is infinity or else zero, which is an ill consideration nevertheless.

Comment: I would think a little more about it, however you gave one example of a limiting process, and others could give different results with the point-wise limit. Could uniform convergence be more appropriate?

Comment: @LaurentDuval That's actually an **intuitive** limit, rather than a formal topological one. I remember that in our signals and systems book, (OppWillsky) the transition from continuous time Fourier series to th continuous time Furier transform was also based on a similar intuitive limiting process, where one thinks of the CTFT as the limit of CTFS when the period goes to infinity (while the signal being nonzero only for a finite length)...

Comment: I understood  the analogy. However, I just got a paper from Feichtinger, on how LTI system courses can be misleading, and wanted to mention the potential caveats

Comment: @LaurentDuval Do you have a link or more details? Sounds like an interesting paper.

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-55556-0_3

Comment: @LaurentDuval Thanks. As an engineer, I'm not convinced that the way we teach should change, but as a professor one should be aware of the mathematical nuances.

Comment: @MBaz just sharing alternative facts :) "Who knows where the road may lead us, only a fool would say. Who knows if we'll meet along the way. " Alan Parsons Project)

Answer (score 3):

> If we take the Fourier transform of any constant signal, we get an
>   impulse at zero, which says that its frequency is zero and, hence, it
>   is non-repeating and its period is infinity.

No, this does not work for a zero signal (Fourier is flat-flat, no impulse). Plus, something over zero is traditionally undefined, and could be any number. And THIS is the  very case here.

A periodic function $P$ is such that its values  repeat  "in some way" at "regular intervals or periods". Trigonometric functions are natural examples. Indeed, you can derive them from the exponential series, which is convergent and its own derivative

This notion of repetition can be multidimensional in the variable $x$. There are multiple avatars for periodicity: the most commonly used are [simply periodic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicFunction.html), [doubly periodic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyPeriodicFunction.html), [triply periodic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriplyPeriodicFunction.html) functions.

In the complex plane (the most useful for signal practitioners so far), you can have a doubly periodic function $P$, with two incommensurate least/fundamental complex periods:

$$P(x+x_1)=P(x+x_2)=P(x)$$

with $x_1/x_2$ is not real. Those are called elliptic functions. If you now restrict to univariate single-valued functions, then a theorem by Jacobi states that is is impossible for them  to have more than two distinct (least/fundamental) periods.

But a periodic function can have "no least period" at all, and this is the case with constant functions:

> The constant function $P(x)=0$ is periodic with any period $x_0$ for all
>   nonzero real numbers $x_0$, so there is no concept analogous to the least
>   period for constant functions.

Comment: ok I understood my mistake and deleted the provokative comment. Now I'm also believing that *a constant is a periodic signal with an undefined fundamental period*. Now I'm happy :-)

Comment: A way clearer definition :) I'll borrow it for my lectures to come :)